# Get Exact Online classification value assigned for an account in Excel cell

Tags: invantive-control

We have the sales representative stored as classification 1 on an Account in Exact Online. The account name can be retrieved using a formula such as `I_EOL_ACT_NAME`.

But in I_EOL_ACT_... I can not find an option to retrieve the code of classification 1 on an Account.

How can I retrieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `I_EOL_ACTCLN_PROPERTY_...`, for example:

```
I_EOL_ACTCLN_PROPERTY_CODE(eol_administration, eol_act_code, 4)
& " - " 
& I_EOL_ACTCLN_PROPERTY_description(eol_administration, eol_act_code, 4)
```

A little bit unlogical: there is a limited number of classifications possible (so it seems a list of columns instead of an additional table), but the Excel function prefix is different.